# Monte Carlo Heat Bath Local Minima

Tags: statistical-mechanics, computational-physics

I am working on a problem where I am trying to find the configuration of a statistical system with the lowest energy. The system is similar to Ising model, it compromises of a lattice where each link between sites can take one of N values. The energy of the system depends on the link values. In order to find such configuration, I first initialize all link variables to random values. Then  I visit all the links in lexicographical order and sample the new value of the link from the local Boltzmann distribution. I repeat this until convergence. However, the problem is that in a trivial case where the minimum energy per site is $ -E_0 $, my algorithm converges to a configuration where  the energy per site is about $ -0.9 E_0 $. Is there a way to get around this issue?

Comment: If this is really a trivial case where you can work out the answer analytically, then it sounds like a bug in your program. (Not a criticism -- actually it's really good to test your code with solvable models where you know the answer so then you know any problems must be bugs). If that's the case then you aren't going to get much help here, but you could try asking a programming question at a stack exchange which covers the language you are using. It could be a simple programming error, or it could be an issue with the configuration of the algorithm -- but we would need more detail to tell.

Comment: If you're sure the problem is getting stuck in a local minimum, then a solution could be to try the initial configuration in a different setting, or to use a technique like [simulated annealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing). If you want to test whether it the issue is that the algorithm is settling into a local maximum, you can always start the program in an initial condition near the true global maximum and see if it can find it.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks. I have made a lot of effort ensuring that it is not a bug. I even made 3D visualizations necessary to ensure that I am performing the proper calculations of probabilities. What I suspect is that my algorithm finds a configuration where changing any of the variables is not energetically favourable. Therefore, by changing one link at a time I never get a lower energy configuration. Do you have any idea what could be done in such a case?

Comment: @Andrew Right, I did that and when I start it from global minima it remains there for as long as I iterate.

Comment: I see. In this case I'd try simulated annealing, which ideally should find different local maxima in the early stages of the algorithm and then settle into the best one. Another (less good but maybe easier to implement) option is to add a "random kick" to your solution every so often to force it away from a local maximum and hope this pushes it toward the global maximum.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks. I will try it. My only worry is that the paper I am trying to reproduce does not say anything about this problem...

Comment: Heh. Well -- it's not guaranteed simulated annealing will work or may require some tuning. But one thing I do know is that people often omit information that they consider "a detail" that is crucial for actually reproducing the results, so don't be put off by that. If you ran into this, probably they did too.